# Blocking ports with iptables

Tags: iptables, ports

I have a server with multiple interfaces (IPs). I'd like to block all ports **on one of the IPs** (I don't want to change anything for other IPs/interfaces), but allow outgoing connections from it. For example, it should be possible to run a IRC client from it, but it should not be possible to simply connect to it from the outside (I'll be connecting from a whitelisted IP).

This is what I got until now:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            IP

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

But these rules don't work. Even when I initiate a connection from this IP, the remote server can't connect back, despite I'm allowing RELATED/ESTABLISHED connections. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, default policy for `OUTPUT` Chain is **ACCEPT**, so the last line:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

isn't necessary.

Then the first line:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

is redundant too because default policy for `INPUT` is **ACCEPT**.

Try with only these two rules and see if it helps:

```
iptables -A INPUT -d IP -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d IP -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifically having an issue with IRC connections?  The IRC server you're trying to connect to may be requiring you to run an `ident` server.  Most IRC clients fake one.  Try allowing incoming connections on port 113 and see if it improves.